# Drop caps in Qt rich text

Tags: qt, richtext

I want to render a PNG with an image and some text, which starts with a drop cap. AFAIK, I can render rich text with `QTextDocument::drawContents`, but how can I add a drop cap surrounded by regular size text?

[image]

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/ftena/qt-snippets/tree/master/richtext) is not exactly what you want but maybe it could help.

Comment: @Tarod thanks, it was a good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper part of the image below is a `QTextBrowser` and the lower one is a rendered transparent `QPixmap` placed on a `QLabel`:

[image]

I haven't tried to render any additional pictures yet as my question stated, but it shouldn't be that hard.

```
    textDocument = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)
    #self.t.setDocument(textDocument)
    textDocument.setDefaultFont(QtGui.QFont("Times New Roman", 12))
    textDocument.setDefaultStyleSheet(".firstcharacter {"
                                   "float: left;"
                                   "color: #903;"
                                   "font-size: 72px;"
                                   "font-family: Monotype Corsiva;"
                                   "margin-top: -16px;"
                                   "margin-bottom: -16px;"
                                   "margin-right: 4px;"
                                   "}")
    textDocument.setHtml('<p>'
                  '<table class="firstcharacter"><tr><td>L</td></tr></table>'
                  'ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris '
                  'tristique lobortis orci ac lacinia. Fusce eu purus eget '
                  'diam vehicula auctor nec eu elit. Morbi consequat facilisis '
                  'orci vel malesuada. Donec ultrices molestie sollicitudin. '
                  'Aliquam pharetra libero enim. Donec et suscipit massa. '
                  'Donec dui odio, dignissim non sodales et, tincidunt a sapien. '
                  'Phasellus elit nibh, adipiscing sed blandit vel, interdum et arcu.'
                  '</p>')
    textDocument.setTextWidth(400)
    img = QtGui.QImage(textDocument.size().toSize(),
                       QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
    img.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
    #img.fill(0xffffffff)
    p = QtGui.QPainter(img)
    p.translate(0, 0) #makes drop cap smoother
    textDocument.drawContents(p)
    p.end()
    self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img))
    img.save(r"d:\testimg.png")
```

References:

- [working with richtext - QTextDocument & QPainter](https://github.com/ftena/qt-snippets/tree/master/richtext)

Comment: Truly awesome! Congratulations :) With your permission, I will update my code in GitHub to use `"float: left;"` properly. Happy coding!